# MS Access 2003: Update form table representation on table change

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

when I do changes in a table and then close it and look in the form which shows it, the updates are not visible until I refresh the form. Can I attach - like, a trigger whenever the table is updated, all forms in which it is present are updated to reflect the new state? The only events I found were Enter and Exit, and those are not what I'm looking for since I will most often edit the data in the actual table, not by Entering and Exiting it within a form.

Comment: Why have you forms open when you are editing a table? Is this with just you as the user or are there several users?

Comment: There is really no reason why I have forms open when I edit a table. Sometimes they are just open. I prefer editing in "pure" table view (for no reasons other than conveniance), and I would like any appearance of that table in forms to refelct the changes. For example, when I clear a table and go back to a form, all records are still there, but the data says "#Deleted" - it is annoying to have to refresh (then they disapear visually as well). As for the other question (this is a lame answer) but I don't know if many or just one person at a time uses this database when it is in service.

Answer (score 1):

*Can I attach - like, a trigger whenever the table is updated, all forms in which it is present are updated to reflect the new state?*

Access versions prior to 2010 offer nothing for this.  Access 2010 added a feature called data macros which can supposedly act somewhat like triggers in other rdbms products.  However I don't know whether data macro capabilities would allow you to refresh selected open forms; I suspect not.

If the issue is the forms *never* update at all after you modify the table data ... until/unless you manually refresh the form ... double-check the Recordset Type property on the Data tab of the form's property sheet.  And if that property is set as Snapshot, change it to Dynaset.

If you can't resolve this any other way, you could build a new form for the table.  Do your table edits in that form.  And in that form's after insert, update, and delete events add code to requery any of the related forms which are open.  But I wouldn't want to do that ...